# MLkit tflite file configuration

Tags: android-studio, path, google-mlkit

i am developing using ML-Kit. But there is a path problem. It's the same as the example, but what's wrong with it? Like this, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy4T1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use ML Kit, you can ignore that message and everything should works fine using ML Kit.

ML Model Binding is another feature that uses codegen to generate a wrapper java class for your model. It's works best when your model has metadata inside.

[Here](https://tfhub.dev/android-studio/collections/ml-model-binding/1) list models with metadata if you want to try.